# The unique form of the Lagrange equation in all coordinate system. Any proof for it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems

If I know why the Euler Lagrange Equation is Equivalent with Newtons second law in Cartesian coordinate system why the Lagrange form is  yet valid with the same form  for other coordinate systems while newton law have a different form in each coordinate system?
(As described at [How are the Euler-Lagrange Equations any more coordinate-invariant than Newton's?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/514079/))

Anyone have a proof for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118768/2451